# Update and Insert Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to use insert and update together in a query how can i use it together for e.g

```
INSERT INTO [Sales_Detail_Table] ([RecieptNumber], [ID], [Quantity] ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
UPDATE       dbo.Medicine
SET           Quantity = ?
WHERE        (ID = ?)
```

i want to update the quantity in the medicine table i.e (Set  medicine.quantity =Medicine.quantity -Sales_Detail_Table Quantity where ID = Sales_detail_table .ID entered )

Comment: I suggest normalizing your database by dropping the quantity field in the Medicine table.  You should be able to calculate it whenever you need it.

Comment: Use trigger fire when you insert in table `Sales_Detail_Table` to update table `Medicine`.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean you would like to use them together? If you want to ensure both actions happen, you can use a transaction for both the INSERT and UPDATE statements. This will ensure that both statements either fail or complete as a single unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both insert and update, look into something like:

```
merge dbo.target main
using #updatedata new
ON main.ID=new.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET main.field=new.field
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (field)
    VALUES (new.field)
```